# Authentication Symfony2 from email link

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

Do you know the tips for authenticate user on a Symfony2 plateform from an email link ?

Many thanks before

Comment: What have you done yet ? Your question is way too generic, and quite hard to answer without some more specifications.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) which has quite a bit built into it for managing users.

We use a similar technique for registering a user.  Here is some basic code (you will need to fill in with error handling and the method that actually finds the user based on the URL parameters:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register/activate/{hash}/{oId}", requirements={"hash"="\w+", "oId"="\d+"}, name="register_byhash")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function registerByHashAction($hash, $oId)
{
    $um = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $um->findUserByHash($hash, $oId); // You will need to supply a method that finds the user and checks the hash

    // Mark the user as now active and save the user here

    $providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
    $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);


    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('welcome');
    return new RedirectResponse($url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Pesudocode:

generate hashed link that is unique to user (e.g. md5(email+timestamp+salt) )
store hash for user in db
Send link to user in email (same email as used in hash)

when user accesses site using link:

fetch hash part from link
match hash against database
if match is found, authenticate, else fail
```

Note I'm not guaranteeing that this is a secure way of doing it by any means (not sure if it's even possible to be secure when authenticating through a link only). Just some ideas to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is implement a custom authentication provider. Authentication provider are responsible for users authentication, using pretty much everything you want: could be a cookie (remember me for example), form data or, in your case, a query string parameter.

You'll need:

- A custom token to store the authentication parameter
- A custom authentication provider that can manage the token and authenticate the user
- some **glue** to wire these components to the security system (mean you need to define a factory and some configurations).

Using an authentication provider you'll have the chance to assign the logged user to a custom security role (as the remember me functionality does), so you'll be able to discriminate logged user from "autologged" user. This could be really useful if you want to restrict what an auto logged user can do(you may want to make the authentication valid for just one specific action for example).

There is a recipe in the official cookbook about Custom authentication provider:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

I've done pretty much what you need to and wrote about it at screenfony.com blog:

http://www.screenfony.com/blog/symfony-custom-authentication-provider